# verilog port mapping syntax error

Tags: verilog

```
Error-[SE] Syntax error
      Following verilog source has syntax error :
      "design.sv", 5: token is '['
        mux4x1 inst1(.sel[0](k), .sel[1](j), .I[0](q), I[1](0), .I[2](1), 
      .I[3](qb), .y(W1));
                          ^

1 error
```

Comment: Please elaborate. Post some code.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot map a signal to an individual bit of a bus. Instead, you will need to map the concatenation of the signals onto the bus as a whole:

```
mux4x1 inst1(.sel({k, j}), .I({q, 2'b01, qb}), .y(W1));
```